# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Uploader_Helper_Data' not found?

Tags: magento-1, error

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Uploader_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /var/www/html/example/app/Mage.php on line 546

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  229960  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0038  5566720 Mage::run( )    .../index.php:106
3   0.0040  5581328 Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ) .../Mage.php:683
4   0.0179  5922552 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( )  .../__default.php:20307
5   0.0197  6106776 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( )   .../__default.php:17620
6   0.0200  6132512 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ) .../__default.php:18067
7   0.1145  6470776 Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction( )    .../__default.php:13672
8   0.1146  6471768 Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage( ) .../IndexController.php:45
9   0.1146  6472680 Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage( )    .../__default.php:10918
10  0.1419  9566760 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout( ) .../__default.php:11003
11  0.1420  9568392 Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput( )    .../__default.php:13643
12  0.1420  9568800 Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml( ) .../__default.php:27696
13  0.1422  9569928 Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml( )    .../__default.php:2518
14  0.1422  9570040 Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView( ) .../__default.php:3281
15  0.1424  9571488 Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView( )  .../__default.php:3267
16  0.1425  9589960 include( '/var/www/html/loveboots/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/page/1column.phtml' ) .../__default.php:3236
17  0.1425  9590408 Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml( )   .../1column.phtml:4
18  0.1425  9590584 Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml( )  .../__default.php:2181
19  0.1425  9590976 Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml( ) .../__default.php:2237
20  0.1426  9591704 Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml( )    .../__default.php:2518
21  0.1426  9591816 Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView( ) .../__default.php:3281
22  0.1427  9592416 Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView( )  .../__default.php:3267
23  0.1427  9611152 include( '/var/www/html/loveboots/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/page/html/head.phtml' )   .../__default.php:3236
24  0.1494  9869048 Mage_Core_Helper_Js->getTranslatorScript( ) .../head.phtml:190
25  0.1494  9869112 Mage_Core_Helper_Js->getTranslateJson( )    .../__default.php:19534
26  0.1494  9869240 Mage_Core_Helper_Js->_getTranslateData( )   .../__default.php:19524
27  0.1520  9924784 Mage::helper( ) .../__default.php:19610
```

please give me any solution? How to solve it?

Comment: Check your dir `app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php` if this file exists?

Comment: Where you face this error?

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php file is exists

Comment: when i run my home page then find error...Prince

Comment: Do you have compilation enabled? If yes, please disable it and check after refreshing cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have compilation enabled? If yes, please disable it and check after refreshing cache. –

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to Magento's compilation process. It is a collection of all your Magento classes. If you face any issue related to `class not found` error, first thing to do is to check your compilation status.

If compilation is enabled, please `re-compile` your classes.
It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search your whole project for the string `module="Uploader"` e.g by using `grep -iR "module='Uploader'` on linux.

Also search for `grep -iR 'module="Uploader"'`, maybe it is wrapped in `'` instead of `"`

Then you will find the file where the problem is caused.

Answer (score 0):

To get the website and admin panel live again, I disabled the compilation via SFTP.

You can do that by editing the root/includes/config.php file.

To disable compilation in Magento, edit includes/config.php, comment out the first line (line 28) and uncomment out the second line (line 29).

Your final code should look like this (without brackets):

[#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(**FILE**).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');] [define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(**FILE**).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');]

Hope this helps.